# How to initialize stdout/stderr in a subsystem=windows program WITHOUT calling AllocConsole()?

Tags: c, winapi, io, console, stdout

So when trying to use the stdin/stdout/stderr streams in a Windows GUI app, one typically has to call AllocConsole (or AttachConsole) in order to initialize those streams for use.  There are lots of posts on here on what you need to do AFTER calling AllocConsole (i.e. use freopen_s on the respective streams, etc).

I have a program where I want to redirect stdout and stderr to an anonymous pipe.  I have a working example where I call:

```
    AllocConsole();

    FILE* fout;
    FILE* ferr;

    freopen_s(&fout, "CONOUT$", "r+", stdout);
    freopen_s(&ferr, "CONOUT$", "r+", stderr);

    HANDLE hreadout;
    HANDLE hwriteout;
    HANDLE hreaderr;
    HANDLE hwriteerr;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sao = { sizeof(sao),NULL,TRUE };
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sae = { sizeof(sae),NULL,TRUE };
    CreatePipe(&hreadout, &hwriteout, &sao, 0);
    CreatePipe(&hreaderr, &hwriteerr, &sae, 0);

    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hwriteout);
    SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, hwriteerr);
```

This snippet successfully sets stdout and stderr to the write ends of the anonymous pipes and I can capture the data.

However calling AllocConsole will spawn a Conhost.exe - this is the actual black window that pops to the screen.  I don't have a use for this and most importantly, I would like to avoid the process creation of a child conhost.exe under my program.

So the question is, how can I fool Windows into thinking it has a console attached/manually setup the initial stdout and stderr file streams so that I can then redirect them as I have done already?  I have looked at the AllocConsole call in a debugger as well as GetStdHandle and SetStdHandle to try and get a sense of what is going on, but my RE skills are lacking.

Without AllocConsole, the freopen_s calls fail with error 6, Invalid Handle.  GetStdHandle also returns a NULL handle.  Calling SetStdHandle succeeds (based on it's return code and calling GetLastError), however this doesn't appear to actually get things set up where I need them as I don't receive any output in my pipe.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the SetStdHandle function to assign your pipe HANDLE values to STD_INPUT_HANDLE and STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE.

Comment: I modified my code (commenting out allocconsole and freopen_s) and after creating my pipes I added:   int fo = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)(hwriteout), _O_TEXT);
 int fe = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)(hwriteerr), _O_TEXT);
 FILE* fWriteout = _fdopen(fo, "r+");
 FILE* fWriteerr = _fdopen(fe, "r+");
 SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, fWriteout);
 SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, fWriteerr);
Also commenting out the original SetStdHandle calls.
Get last error says nothing failed, but I don't capture the output in my pipe.

Comment: Additionally I called GetStdHandle after doing the above but got back a NULL handle.  So it still seems that it needs to be initialized somehow @SoronelHaetir